# How to import android studio project in eclipse which use library?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, import, runtime-error

When we import android studio project in eclipse it shows following error.

Android studio project contains project and library when we import all compile time error is solved but when we run project from eclipse it shows error.

project link = "https://github.com/glomadrian/material-code-input"
And bellow is my xml layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#FFF"

    >


  <com.github.glomadrian.codeinputlib.CodeInput
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:hint_text="Pairing code"
      android:id="@+id/pairing"
      />

  <com.github.glomadrian.codeinputlib.CodeInput
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:underline_color="#457ad1"
      app:underline_selected_color="#9e1ace"
      app:text_color="#b12eff"
      app:hint_color="#77ce9d"
      app:hint_text="Pin code"
      app:codes="4"
      />

  <com.github.glomadrian.codeinputlib.CodeInput
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:underline_color="#d19385"
      app:underline_selected_color="#ce3a47"
      app:text_color="#5c282c"
      app:hint_color="#ce1087"
      app:hint_text="Cheat code"
      app:codes="8"
      />

  <com.github.glomadrian.codeinputlib.CodeInput
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:underline_color="#03A9F4"
      app:underline_selected_color="#3F51B5"
      app:text_color="#212121"
      app:hint_color="#03A9F4"
      app:hint_text="Hash code"
      app:codes="10"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the screenshot.

[image: Runtime error when import android studio project in eclipse]

Comment: Can you post the xml layout file used by this activity ?

Comment: above is my xml file

Comment: You just have to upgrade eclipse version and sdk to get support of V7. There you go....

Answer (score 3):

your project seem's to have material design 
 
you have to add a project called material design from this link https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary into your workspace 
after that go into your project and go to properties->android->add and choose material design library from there